# Regex product url after change domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, shopify

The current situation is as follows:

- Ecommerce site on shopify on primary domain mysite.com

We are developing a new showcase website only for the brand (developed in wordpress) which must have the primary domain mysite.com and the shop on shopify will have a subdomain shop.mysite.com
So far no problem.
When they are launched, you need to set a REGEX that can redirect the products to the new domain.

The redirect must do this:

**[www.mysite.com/collections/name-category/product/?](http://www.mysite.com/collections/name-category/product/?)***
to
**[www.shop.mysite.com/collections/name-category/product/?](http://www.shop.mysite.com/collections/name-category/product/?)***

I was thinking of testing like this:

RewriteRule ^collections/(.*) http://www.shop.mysite.com/collections/$1 [R=301,L]

is an easy way to make this redirect? or i have to make it one by one?

Comment: I was thinking of testing like this:

RewriteRule ^collections/name-category/product/(.*) http://www.shop.mysite.com/collections/name-category/product/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from testing it, and checking if it works as desired?

Comment: the new site is still offline, so I'd like to be sure it worked, since it's a big ecommerce brand it can't afford to be offline or SEO drops

Comment: Surely you will have some sort of development environment set up for this, so go test it in there.

Comment: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/domains/add-a-domain/connecting-domains/connect-subdomain